Jupyter kernel in vscode crashes after installing numpyro
I have created an python environment using conda (python 3.12) which includes geopandas and numpyro. The minute I install numpyro using either pip or conda/mamba (I tried both), My jupyter kernel crashes with the following error undefined symbol: sqlite3_deserialize
{
"name": "",
"message": "",
"stack": "Failed to start the Kernel. 

ImportError: /home/imantha/software/mamba/envs/lo2hi/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_deserialize. 
View Jupyter <a href='command:jupyter.viewOutput'>log</a> for further details."
}

By the way this behavior is in jupyter in vscode + ubuntu machine.
Any clue how to fix this ?

Any of the discussion here provide insight?

Thanks possibly. I got it working with python 3.10. Wasn't able to get it working with python 3.10

ahh yes ! I meant to say, couldn't get it to work with python 3.12 but works fine with 3.10
